# boost::asio -- asio_handler_deallocate is called in io_service::~io_service(), after io_service::stop()

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have an `ip::udp::socket` constructed with an `io_service`. There is only one `boost::thread` which calls the `io_service::run()` method, and an instance of `io_service::work` to prevent `io_service::run()` from returning. The completion handlers for my `ip::udp::socket` have custom `asio_handler_allocate()` and `asio_handler_deallocate()` functions, which are backed by a `my::custom_memory_pool`.

When my application quits, this sequence of events occurs on on my shutting-down thread:

1. `ip::udp::socket::close()`
2. `work::~work()`
3. `io_service::stop()`
4. `thread::join()`
5. `my::custom_memory_pool::~custom_memory_pool()`
6. `ip::udp::socket::~socket()`
7. `thread::~thread()`
8. `io_service::~io_service()`

In step 8, the call to `io_service::~io_service()` causes...

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00000000005ad93c in my::custom_memory_pool<boost::aligned_storage<512u, -1u> >::deallocate (this=0x36323f8, t=0x7fca97a07880)
    at memory.hpp:82
82                      reinterpret_cast<pool_node*>(t)->next_ = head_;
(gdb) bt 30
#0  0x00000000005ad93c in my::custom_memory_pool<boost::aligned_storage<512u, -1u> >::deallocate (this=0x36323f8, t=0x7fca97a07880)
    at memory.hpp:82
#1  0x00000000005ad40a in asio_handler_deallocate (p=0x7fca97a07880, s=96, h=0x7fffe09d5480) at net.cpp:22
#2  0x0000000000571a07 in boost_asio_handler_alloc_helpers::deallocate<socket_multicast::completion_handler> (p=0x7fca97a07880, s=96, h=...)
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/handler_alloc_helpers.hpp:51
#3  0x0000000000558256 in boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_recvfrom_op<boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::udp>, socket_multicast::completion_handler>::ptr::reset (this=0x7fffe09d54b0)
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/reactive_socket_recvfrom_op.hpp:81
#4  0x0000000000558310 in boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_recvfrom_op<boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::udp>, socket_multicast::completion_handler>::do_complete (owner=0x0, base=0x7fca97a07880)
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/reactive_socket_recvfrom_op.hpp:112
#5  0x0000000000426706 in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation::destroy (this=0x7fca97a07880)
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/task_io_service_operation.hpp:41
#6  0x000000000042841b in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::shutdown_service (this=0xd4df30)
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/task_io_service.ipp:96
#7  0x0000000000426388 in boost::asio::detail::service_registry::~service_registry (this=0xd4a320, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/service_registry.ipp:43
#8  0x0000000000428e99 in boost::asio::io_service::~io_service (this=0xd49f38, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/impl/io_service.ipp:51
```

So the `io_service::~io_service()` is trying to deallocate some memory to the pool that I destroyed back in step 5.

I can't move `my::custom_memory_pool::~custom_memory_pool()` to after `io_service::~io_service()`.

I expected that after `io_service::stop()` and `thread::join()` returns, there could be no more `asio_handler_deallocate()` calls. Apparently that's not the case. What can I do in step 3 to force `io_service` to dequeue all of its completion events and deallocate all of its handler memory, and how can I block until `io_service` finishes those tasks?

Comment: Maybe I should move `work::~work()` to come after `io_service::stop()`... perhaps I'm not giving the `io_service` the opportunity to complete all operations.

Comment: If you're explicitly calling stop, then when you destory the `work` is irrelevant.  The work only prevents the io_service from automatically stoping when it has no further tasks pending.

Comment: The asio docs: `io_service::stop()` means "Subsequent calls to run(), run_one(), poll() or poll_one() will return immediately." `work::~work()` means the end of the requirement that "the io_service object's run() function will not exit while work is underway." So the more I think about it, the more it seems that the proper order must be `io_service::stop()` then `work::~work()`, but the docs aren't explicit about that.

Comment: The order is irrelevant.  By default, `run()` only returns when the io_service is stopped or there is no work (either a `work` object or a pending asynchronous operation) to do.  By adding a `work` object, it prevents the latter of those cases.   Explicit calls to stop cause the run/run_one/... functions to return as soon as possible, and further calls to return immediately.  Calling `io_service::reset()` will then allow processing to restart.  That is why `stop` does not remove the handlers, because there would be no way to restart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer: When tearing down an `io_service` and its services, don't call `io_service::stop()` at all. Just `work::~work()`.

`io_service::stop()` is really only for temporarily suspending the `io_service` so that it may be `io_service::reset()` later. An ordinary graceful shutdown of `io_service` should not involve `io_service::stop()`.

Comment: This answer is simply wrong. stop() and ~work() do not do the same things. ~work() finishes all pending work, which can take (potentially infinite) time, whereas stop() cancels calls blocked on asynchronous operations. If you terminate your application, you wanna call stop() for obvious reasons (program must terminate asap).

Comment: Are you sure @Kenji ? `stop()` doesn't cancel any I/O calls, it will only [Stop the io_service object's event processing loop](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/stop.html). There's more to say about uses for stop(), but I think "simply wrong" is a bit of an overstatement. – James Brock

Comment: Yes @James, it doesn't cancel I/O calls/pending work. It just makes all threads blocked on calls like run() exit the function as soon as possible. In the meantime, I actually learned that you MUST NOT call `io_service::stop()` before destroying io_service because the library will segfault sometimes - it's incapable of cleaning up the rest of the pending operations. A shame, but apparently "works as intended", as expert users of the library reassured me - they also said this behaviour is documented, but I did not find it anywhere. So there's really no simple and sane way to end io_service.

Comment: `whereas stop() cancels calls blocked on asynchronous operations` what I meant here is that it cancels (returns from) run() calls which are blocked because there is pending work.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `io_service::stop()` doesn't allow it to finish any handlers, it simply stops processing after any currently running handler and returns as soon as possible.

Since the various internal structures are destroyed when the `io_service` is destroyed, one solution is to control the order that the io_service is destroyed relative to the custom allocator.  Either order them correctly if they're in the same structure (have the allocator prior to the io_service in the structure), or use the heap and explicitly order their destruction to guarantee that the `io_service` is destroyed first.

Comment: +1 It's true that `io_service::stop()` will force `io_service::run()` to return immediately, and that any enqueued completion handlers in the `io_service` persist and may be dequeued later, after `io_service::reset()`. I tested this.